# Enable Account Teams in scratch org definition file

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org, account-teams, unlocked-package, scratch-org-definition-file

Is there a way to enable Account Teams in a scratch org definition file? I know I can manually enable it in a scratch org via Setup, but in order to create an unlocked package version that contains Apex code referencing the AccountTeamMember object, I need to enable it in the definition file. But I don't see a way to do this from looking at the Salesforce documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's in the Account Settings area. Here's the relevant JSON to start from:

```
{
    "settings": {
        "accountSettings": {
            "enableAccountTeams": true
        }
    }
}
```

See [Scratch Org Definition Configuration Values](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_def_file_config_values.htm) for other settings. Edit: There appears to be values missing from the docs. I'll ask about this. However, I do know this setting works, as I copied it from my own org's configuration file.

Comment: Thanks! It worked for me as well. Hopefully it gets added to the docs to avoid future confusion.

Comment: What about opportunity teams? I figured I could use the same format replacing "account" with "opportunity", but it didn't work.

Comment: @JeffFreeman `{ "settings": { "opportunitySettings": { "enableOpportunityTeam": true } } }` should do the trick. For some reason, there's no S in Team.