# Error creating a package version with Opportunity Teams

Tags: unmanaged-package, opportunity-teams

I'm trying to package an unmanaged package using opportunity teams, but each time I get the following error:

`ERROR running force:package:version:create: Invalid type: OpportunityTeamMember`

I tried following the advice in this post: [Enable Account Teams in scratch org definition file](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/296872/enable-account-teams-in-scratch-org-definition-file), but it didn't work.
Sales teams are enabled in my dev hub org, and the scratch org.

Has anyone been able to create a package version with Sales Teams?

update: Here is my project-scratch-def.json:

```
  "orgName": "Demo company",
  "edition": "Developer",
  "features": [],
  "settings": {
    "lightningExperienceSettings": {
      "enableS1DesktopEnabled": true
    },
    "securitySettings": {
      "passwordPolicies": {
        "enableSetPasswordInApi": true
      }
    },
    "mobileSettings": {
      "enableS1EncryptedStoragePref2": false
    },
    "accountSettings": {
      "enableAccountTeams": true
    },
    "opportunitySettings": {
       "enableOpportunityTeam": true 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: so you enabled Opportunity Teams or Account teams in your Scratch org definition file?
do you do any manual step related to OpportunityTeamMember after Scratch Org creation?

Comment: Yes, I enabled the opp & account teams in my scratch org definition, and no I don't need to make any manual adjustments - the Opp teams are enabled when I create a scratch org.

Comment: Strange but [this post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/335533/55891) suggests that it's not possible / officially supported for Opportunity Team enabling in the scratch org settings.  But you just mentioned you got it working in the scratch org itself...